# codeigniter dispaly currency symbol after value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem, the currency symbol shows up in front of the value numbers. How can I position it after the value of the product?
I think the code is the following, where "sym" goes for the row sym in the currency DB:

```
echo $sess[0]->sym.$this->Currency->convert($product[0]->product_price, $product[0]->product_currency, $sess[0]->currency, $currency);
```

I'm new into `PHP/MySQL`

Comment: Without knowing what your `Currency` library does, it's pretty much impossible to provide any guidance. You'd probably need to tweat that, but it's hard to tell without knowing which currency conversion library you are using and seeing some code

Comment: It's also possible that this comes down to localisation settings for the currency.  If the currency is GBP, then the standard is to have the currency prior to the value, some others will be after the currency.  Which currency is this for?

Comment: i think this is the code u talking about: https://codeshare.io/arwm7Z (this is for RON, Romanian Leu, which normally displays after the numbers: XXXron or XXXlei)